# Firebase Web (Sign In for Email) not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been struggling to get Firebase Auth to work for my website. **I'm using a local server to run the HTML code.**

*Firebase is signing up users successfully* (they show up in my Firebase console), but **it's not signing them in**.

I am using this code to check if user is signed in. It always shows "User is not signed in."

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    console.log(user);
    console.log('User is signed in');
  } else {
    console.log(user);
    console.log('User is not signed in');
  }
});
```

I've gone through the documentation and watched the Firecast videos as well as some other tutorials.

My HTML code:

```
<div class="login w3-display-middle">
  <form class="login-container">
    <p><input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email"></p>
    <p><input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"></p>
    <p><button class="w3-blue" id="signin" style="width:100%">LOG IN </button></p>
    <p><button class="w3-blue" id="signup" style="width:100%">SIGN UP </button></p>
    <p><button class="w3-red" id="signout" style="width:100%">SIGN OUT </button></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Javascript (included right **below** the HTML code, before the body tag is closed:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: <I have included my apiKey>,
    authDomain: <I have included my authDomain>,
    databaseURL: <Included my database URL>,
    projectId: <Used my project ID>,
    storageBucket: <Used this as well>,
    messagingSenderId: <And this too>
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

<script>
  const txtEmail = document.getElementById("email");
  const txtPassword = document.getElementById("password");

  signin.addEventListener('click', e => {
    //Get email and password
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass = txtPassword.value;
    console.log(txtEmail.value);//Shows correct value
    console.log(txtPassword.value);//Shows correct value
    const promise = firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
  });

  signup.addEventListener('click', e => {
    //Get email and password
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();

    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass)
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error.code);
      console.log(error.message);
    });
  });

  signout.addEventListener('click',e=> {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
      // Sign-out successful.
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error.code);
      console.log(error.message);
    });
  });

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      console.log(user);
      console.log('User is signed in');
    } else {
      console.log(user);
      console.log('User is not signed in');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Really need help figuring this one out. I've spent like 4 hours on it now. Also, when I initially signup the user, it also signs them in (shows up in the Firebase console!). It's just so weird.

Comment: Do you have email+password sign-in enabled in your Firebase console?

Comment: When you create a user, they are automatically signed in.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen Yes, they are automatically signed in (which is correct). But sign out isn't working and the AuthStateChanged doesn't reflect the changes in the console...

Comment: What happens when you `signOut()`? Are you getting an error? Can you check localStorage is cleared?

Comment: @bojeil Nothing happens when I click on signOut(). Can you please guide me on how to check localStorage? (I'll Google it, but if you can tell me specifically what I need to do, it'll help a lot). Thanks :)